# Lilypond (v2.24) macro delivers unexpected results

Tags: guitar, lilypond, lily-scheme

Writing up a piece for guitar I'm not happy with the common strumming tabulature 'stroke up' and 'stroke down' symbols (^\downbow, ^\upbow) and want to replace them with up- and down arrow heads. In itself not a problem,

`^\markup { \arrow-head #Y #DOWN ##f }` adjacent to the note at hand would do the trick but is a lot of repeated text.

`e''8^\markup { \arrow-head #Y #DOWN ##f } fis''8  d'8 d''8` for instance gives:

[image: arrow head down, no macro]

So I found [a page describing new markup definitions](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/extending/new-markup-command-definition) and wrote the following:

```
#(define-markup-command (arrup layout props text) (markup?)
  "Draw a arrow head down (guitar pick stroke-up)."
  (interpret-markup layout props
    #{\markup { \arrow-head #Y #UP ##f } #}))
```

Then tried to apply it

`e''8^\markup { \arrow-head #Y #DOWN ##f } fis''^\markup \arrup d'8 d''8`, which resulted in:
[image: arrow head down-up with macro]

It's clear that the arrow-up is drawn, but the next following note (d') is gone.

How do I correct this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is very simple: in the first line of the definition, you have

> #(define-markup-command (arrup layout props **text**) (**markup?**)

The words in the first set of parentheses are the function name and its arguments. Here you declare that it will have three (`layout`, `props` and `text`). The first two are supplied automatically, and the third one is "free". So you declare this to be a markup function with *one parameter*. The next list `(markup?)` gives a list of "types" for the free parameters (here for the parameter `text`); in this case, it says that the function `markup?`, upon being called with the parameter, needs to return `#t`.

So after writing `\markup \arrup d'8`, the `d'8` is gobbled up — the function needs a parameter, so it will grab the next token and make it its parameter. Removing the bolded parts will make it work (the `(markup?)` needs to be reduced to `()`, since you still need to have  the list of parameter "types" in there — even though it's empty).

---

But this solution is needlessly complicated. Why not just write

```
arrup = \markup { \arrow-head #Y #UP ##f }
```

and then use it like this: `c^\arrup d e f`? The definition is much simpler, and it's easier to use.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to remove 'text', but that resulted in an error, and I don't understand the (markup?) so didn't try to remove that yet. Unfortunately none of your 2 solutions work. The 1st gives error: Guile signaled an error for the expression beginning here
{#
  (define-markup-command (arrup layout props)
Syntax error:
unknown location: source expression failed to match any pattern in form (list . "Draw a arrow head down (guitar pick stroke-up).")

Comment: The 2nd: 
arrup = \markup { \arrow-head #Y #UP ##f }
fis''^\arrup
results in:
error: not a note name: arrup
arrup = \markup { \arrow-head #Y #UP ##f }
and 
syntax error, unexpected '='
arrup 
      = \markup { \arrow-head #Y #UP ##f }

Comment: This however works:  arrup = \markup { \arrow-head #Y #UP ##f } \absolute { fis''^\arrup d'8 d''8 }

Comment: So the declarations of arrup and arrdown should have been done before the 'include' statement loading the guitar notes. I had tried arrup= and arrdown= before, but because of the wrong placement in the file it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HarryH: that's weird because I tested them and they both worked. Of course you need to define things *before* they are used. As for the first solution, I should perhaps have made it more clear that you need to remove only the `markup?` so that a pair of empty parentheses is left behind.

Comment: I thought of that, but your enclosing parentheses appeared bold faced, so I removed them too. Thanks though.

Comment: The first error message sounds like you wrote "{#" instead of the correct "#{".